# C optional input on Windows console

Tags: c, windows, input, console, scanf

This code doesn't work:

```
_tprintf(TEXT("Enter password or press enter to skip: "));
pszPassword = new TCHAR[100];
int numFields = _tscanf_s(TEXT("%s"), pszPassword, 100);
if (numFields == 0) // never reached
{
    delete[] pszPassword;
    pszPassword = NULL;
}
```

Pressing enter doesn't make `scanf` abort parsing the input, because it skips over whitespace until non-whitespace characters are found.

How can I achieve the desired behaviour?

The program is actually in C, I use `new` and `delete` instead of `malloc` but wouldn't like to use `std::string` etc.

Comment: Don´t do scanf on strings. Use fgets etc.

Comment: Is there a C-style way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing in C instead of C++ using `fgets`, and it works:

```
TCHAR *pszPassword = malloc(100 * sizeof (TCHAR));

_tprintf(TEXT("Enter password or press enter to skip: "));
_fgetts(pszPassword, 100, stdin) ;

if (pszPassword[0] == '\n')
{
  free(pszPassword) ;
  pszPassword = NULL;
}
```